# Unittest and doctest, how to make my files callable?

Tags: python, unit-testing, call, doctest

I have a folder with python scripts that contain doc tests that I want to do unit tests on. When I try to test it with one file like this:

```
import unittest
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest('/homes/ndeklein/workspace/MS/PyMS/pyMS/baseFunctions.py')
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: the test to add must be callable
```

However, when I do it from the commandline

```
python '/homes/ndeklein/workspace/MS/PyMS/pyMS/baseFunctions.py'
```

it works.

How can I make my file callable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addTest` takes a `TestCase` or a `TestSuite` - and you're passing in a string.

Have a look at the docs here:

http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html

It's not clear exactly what you want to do - but if `baseFunctions.py` defines a subclass of `TestCase`, you could try this:

```
import unittest
from baseFunctions import MyTestCase

suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(MyTestCase)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```